# dependency injection vs constructor overload

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am working on a .net core project where each controller has their own service as DI. All those services share some common stuff so I abstract a `BaseService` class:

```
public class BaseService
{
    public BaseService(IHttpContextService srv)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This `BaseService`, or in another word, all the services need another service for the HTTP context.

Now I need to inherit from this `BaseService` if I need a new service for a new controller:

```
public class MyFirstService : BaseService
{
    public MyFirstService(IHttpContextService srvHttp, AdditionalService srvAdditional) {}
}
```

In its constructor, I will need to specify the `IHttpContextService` again, and a few additional services this `MyFirstService` needs.

But this seems wrong because the child is a descendant and therefore should have the `IHttpContextService` naturally. Not to mention the child doesn't have a constructor with the same parameters as the ancestor which gives a compile error.

Is there a way to DI objects outside of the constructor? Or just get rid of the DI from .net core? Or I should change my design pattern?

Comment: Derived classes _have to_ construct their base classes.

Comment: I hesitate to suggest it, but property injection in `BaseService` might help in this case.

Comment: @John correct me if i am wrong but your suggestion seems that I have to remove the inheritance hierarchy and introduce the `BaseService` as DI into each child?

Comment: @madreflection I googled the property injection. It seems that everytime when I need the child service, I have to new the `IHttpContextService` and assign it to a property?

Comment: No. You would make a public property of type `IHttpContextService` and then figure out how your container supports property injection. Some use an attribute on the property, for example. It might look like this: `[Inject] public IHttpContextService HttpContextService { get; set; }` .  The container would assign the property after creating the instance and it wouldn't have to be passed in the constructor. You just can't access it in the constructors.

Comment: Just note that property injection is considered by some to be "impure" dependency injection, which is why I hesitated to suggest it.

Comment: No, I'm saying that it is the responsibility of a derived class to call the base class' constructor, although .NET does this automatically for you in clear-cut cases (i.e. no base constructor, or a parameterless base constructor). So essentially, you use property injection as suggested by madreflection, you accept the service via the derived constructor and pass it to the base, or you separate the base from the derived class altogether as you suggested.

Comment: @madreflection These some did not understand the term "dependency injection" - because it only means to inject any dependency. period.

Comment: @madreflection I am not using any containers. All .net core built-in stuff.

Comment: I assume you mean *ASP* .NET  Core. It has a built-in container. I know it supports property injection because it injects services into Razor views via the `@inject` directive.

Comment: `But this seems wrong because the child is a descendant and therefore should have the IHttpContextService naturally.` That isn't how inheritance works nor how constructors work. The child has to **give** the parameter to the parent. The base class doesn't magically receive it.

Comment: `Not to mention the child doesn't have a constructor with the same parameters as the ancestor which gives a compile error.` You should use `public MyFirstService(IHttpContextService srvHttp, AdditionalService srvAdditional) : base(srvHttp) {}`.